# how to select by classname in angular from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I am trying to get an inner value of an element by selecting through the class in angular. But for some reason it keeps giving me an error when I try to select `var highlighted = angular.element(element.getElementsByClassName("btn-danger"));` This is the error
`angular.js:13642TypeError: angular.element.getElementsByClassName is not a function`
Could it be because I am mixing angular and jquery together

the main problem is in the click controller.
it gets the value of the ul that gets loaded with the json and supposed to show on the bottom in the mouse click me(the number is just for testing)

the project is a single click keyboard that will eventually have an interval and switch keys so a disabled person can type with only one click

here is the view

```
<body ng-controller="mainController"   ng-click="textArea = textArea + 1">


    <div ng-controller="clickController">

        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Click and Type</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="container">

            <div ng-controller="intervalController">

                <ul class="general_button" ng-repeat="letter in language[0].rows track by $index" ng-init="rowIndex = $index"> {{rowIndex}}
                    <button type="button" class="btn " ng-class="{true:'btn-danger', false:'btn-info'}[rowIndex ==isSelected() || columnIndex == isSelected()]" ng-repeat="single in letter track by $index" ng-init="columnIndex = $index"> 
                         {{columnIndex}}{{single}}
                    </button>
                </ul>

                <div  >

                     <h1 ng-mousemove="textArea = textArea + 1">Mouse over me!</h1>

                    <label for="inputlg">input-lg</label>
                    <input class="form-control input-lg" id="inputlg" type="text" value="{{ textArea + highlightedLetter }}">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the model

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
var theLanguage = 'english';
App.factory('jsonLanguage', function($http){
    var theLanguage = 'english';
    return {

        get: function(theLanguage){
            //var url = theLanguage + '.json';
            var url = 'english.json';
            return $http.get(url);
        }
    }

});
App.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, $log, jsonLanguage) {


    jsonLanguage.get().then(function(res){
        $scope.language = res.data;
        $log.log($scope.language);
    });

    $scope.isSelected = function(rowIndex, columnIndex) {
        return 0;

    }



});

App.controller('intervalController', function($scope, $log) {
    this.$log = $log;
    //var name = $scope.single;

    //$log.log(name);


});

App.controller('clickController', function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.$log = $log;
    var highlighted = angular.element(angular.element.getElementsByClassName("btn-danger"));
    alert($scope.highlightedLetter = highlighted.value);
});
```

I greatly appreciate any help as I am new to angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `getElementsByClassName` method in Jquery. Try using standard DOM query:

```
var highlighted = angular.element(document.querySelector(".btn-danger"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` is a function of DOM element, not jQuery.

Try this, it might help you:

```
var classElement = document.getElementsByClassName("multi-files");
var highlighted= angular.element(classElement);
```

Comment: naming variables using special names like class is never good practice, in this situation class name is very not desirable because this variable contains DOMCollection, so naming as classElements would be much better.

Comment: I edited as per your suggestion. I just wanted to give him an idea as how to solve his problem